# Describe all extensions of the identity map of $\mathbb{Q}$ to an isomorphism mapping $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2},\sqrt{3})$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, ring-theory, finite-groups

Here is the full question : Describe all extensions of the identity map of $\mathbb{Q}$ to an isomorphism mapping $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2},\sqrt{3})$ onto a subfield of the algebraic closure of $\mathbb{Q}$

Given that $\alpha_1$ = $\sqrt[3]{2}$, $\alpha_2$ = $\sqrt[3]{2}(\omega)$ , $\alpha_3$ = $\sqrt[3]{2}(\omega^2)$, could someone please help me figure out what this question is trying to entail?

$\omega$ is the cubic root of unity.

I don't understand what an extension of the identity map is.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: The identity map in $\Bbb Q$ is the isomorphism $\phi$ that doesn't do _anything_, i.e. $\phi(x) = x$ for all $x$. An extension of $\phi$ is an isomorphism $\phi':\Bbb Q(\sqrt[3]{2},\sqrt{3}) \to \Bbb Q(\sqrt[3]{2},\sqrt{3})$ such that $\phi'|_{\Bbb Q} = \phi$, or in other words, it is an automorphism of $\Bbb Q(\sqrt[3]{2},\sqrt{3})$ that looks like $\phi$ if you just look at $\Bbb Q$. What is $\omega$?

Comment: $\omega$ is the cubic root of unity. Sorry, I should have clarified.

Comment: Doesn't do anything.. in what sense? I'm still trying to figure out how the identity map connects with the three roots, the roots themselves look confusing but I understand how they were derived.

Comment: To use a more familiar example, say you have the fields $\Bbb R \subseteq \Bbb C$, and the identity morphism $\phi:\Bbb R \to \Bbb R$ given by $\phi(x) = x$ (it doesn't do anything in the sense that applying this morphism changes nothing). Then there are two extensions of $\phi$ to the complex numbers $\Bbb C$. One is the identity morphism $\phi_0$ on $\Bbb C$, that is, $\phi_0(x + yi) = x + yi$. The other one, $\phi_1$, is complex conjugation: $\phi_1(x + yi) = x-yi$. Note that if the complex number we have happens to be _real_ (i.e. $y = 0$), then they both coincide with the original $\phi$.

Comment: @Arthur FWIW $\phi^\prime$ isn't required to be into $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2},\sqrt{3}$.

Comment: SquiresMcGee, the question is to find every isomorphism of  $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2},\sqrt{3})$ into another algebraic extension of $\mathbb{Q}$ such that the restriction of the isomrophism to $\mathbb{Q}$ is the identity map. We might ask, what possible images $\sqrt[3]{2}$ and $\sqrt{3}$ have under such an isomorphism.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well it is not so hard, given any $x\in \mathbb{Q}(2^{1/3},3^{1/2})$ then you know that $x$ will be written as :

$$x=\sum_{n,k}a_{n,k}(2^{1/3})^n(3^{1/2})^k \text{ where } a_{n,k}\in\mathbb{Q}$$

I have just said that the elements of this field can be written as polynomials of $2^{1/3}$ and $3^{1/2}$ (it is almost trivial from the definition of the field, the only thing to show is that $(2^{1/3})^{-1}$ and $(3^{1/2})^{-1}$ are also polynomials).

Now take $\phi$ to be a ring morphism fixing $\mathbb{Q}$ point by point then :

$$\phi(x)=\sum_{n,k}\phi(a_{n,k})\phi(2^{1/3})^n\phi(3^{1/2})^k $$

In other words $\phi$ is only defined by its values on $2^{1/3}$ and $3^{1/2}$.

Finally $\phi(2^{1/3})^3-2=\phi((2^{1/3})^3-2)=\phi(0)=0$, in other words $\phi(2^{1/3})$ is a root of $X^3-2$ i.e. $\phi(2^{1/3})\in\{\alpha_1,\alpha_2,\alpha_3\}$.

For the same reason $\phi(3^{1/2})\in \{\pm3^{1/2}\}$.

Now it is easy to see (it actually depends on your technical background, I leave the details to you) that all these choices gives one isomorphism. So there are $3\times 2=6$ isomorphisms from your field into another subfield of $\mathbb{C}$ and only two of them are automorphisms of $\mathbb{Q}(2^{1/3},3^{1/2})$ (to be an automorphism you must fix $\alpha_1$).

Answer (score 1):

An element in $\Bbb Q(\sqrt[3]{2},\sqrt{3})$ is of the form
$$
a + b\sqrt[3]2 + c\sqrt[3]4 +d\sqrt3+ e\sqrt3\sqrt[3]2+f\sqrt3\sqrt[3]4
$$
where $a, b, c, d, e, f \in \Bbb Q$. A rational number will have $b = c = d = e = f= 0$.The identity map $\phi$ on $\Bbb Q$ is given by $\phi(x) = x$. An extension of $\phi$ means a map $\phi':\Bbb Q(\sqrt[3]{2},\sqrt{3}) \to \overline{\Bbb Q}$ where $\phi'(x) = x$, as long as $x$ is rational ($\overline{\Bbb Q}$ is the algebraic closure of $\Bbb Q$). The problem wants us to find *all* injective homomorphisms fulfilling this.

We can start with the obvious one, namely the identity morphism $\phi_0$, with
$$
\phi_0(a + b\sqrt[3]2 + c\sqrt[3]4 +d\sqrt3+ e\sqrt3\sqrt[3]2+f\sqrt3\sqrt[3]4)\\ = a + b\sqrt[3]2 + c\sqrt[3]4 +d\sqrt3+ e\sqrt3\sqrt[3]2+f\sqrt3\sqrt[3]4
$$ Then we get to the first $\omega$-related homomorphism which I call $\phi_\omega$, where we send $\sqrt[3]{2}$ to $\omega\sqrt[3]{2}$. This means that
$$
\phi_\omega(a + b\sqrt[3]2 + c\sqrt[3]4 +d\sqrt3+ e\sqrt3\sqrt[3]2+f\sqrt3\sqrt[3]4)\\ = a + b\omega\sqrt[3]2 + c\omega^2\sqrt[3]4 +d\sqrt3+ e\omega\sqrt3\sqrt[3]2+f\omega^2\sqrt3\sqrt[3]4
$$
The other one, nicknamed $\phi_{\omega^2}$ works similarily, by
$$
\phi_\omega(a + b\sqrt[3]2 + c\sqrt[3]4 +d\sqrt3+ e\sqrt3\sqrt[3]2+f\sqrt3\sqrt[3]4)\\ = a + b\omega^2\sqrt[3]2 + c\omega^4\sqrt[3]4 +d\sqrt3+ e\omega^2\sqrt3\sqrt[3]2+f\omega^4\sqrt3\sqrt[3]4\\
= a + b\omega^2\sqrt[3]2 + c\omega\sqrt[3]4 +d\sqrt3+ e\omega^2\sqrt3\sqrt[3]2+f\omega\sqrt3\sqrt[3]4
$$
Now, there is one other way of mapping a number in $\Bbb Q(\sqrt[3]{2},\sqrt{3})$, and that is by sending $\sqrt3$ to $-\sqrt3$. This gives the homomorphism $\phi_-$, which is defined by
$$
\phi_-(a + b\sqrt[3]2 + c\sqrt[3]4 +d\sqrt3+ e\sqrt3\sqrt[3]2+f\sqrt3\sqrt[3]4)\\ = a + b\sqrt[3]2 + c\sqrt[3]4 -d\sqrt3- e\sqrt3\sqrt[3]2-f\sqrt3\sqrt[3]4
$$
We can of course combine $\phi_-$ with either $\phi_\omega$ or $\phi_{\omega^2}$ to get $\phi_{-,\omega}$ and $\phi_{-, \omega^2}$, with
$$
\phi_{-,\omega}(a + b\sqrt[3]2 + c\sqrt[3]4 +d\sqrt3+ e\sqrt3\sqrt[3]2+f\sqrt3\sqrt[3]4)\\ = a + b\omega\sqrt[3]2 + c\omega^2\sqrt[3]4 -d\sqrt3- e\omega\sqrt3\sqrt[3]2-f\omega^2\sqrt3\sqrt[3]4$$
and
$$
\phi_{-,\omega^2}(a + b\sqrt[3]2 + c\sqrt[3]4 +d\sqrt3+ e\sqrt3\sqrt[3]2+f\sqrt3\sqrt[3]4)\\ = a + b\omega^2\sqrt[3]2 + c\omega\sqrt[3]4 -d\sqrt3- e\omega^2\sqrt3\sqrt[3]2-f\omega\sqrt3\sqrt[3]4
$$
The answer by Clément Guérin explains why these are the only homomorphisms you can get. Note that the notation for the different $\phi$ are in no way standard, so you would have to explain them just as I have if you do this on an exam or in a hand-in or on a blackboard just among classmates.

Comment: Thanks Arthur, the help is much appreciated.